# Feasibility of Flailing Ooze

Tags: biology, creature-design, mythical-creatures

This creature is an amorphous mass of ooze coated with a slimy, protective membrane (think a biological equivalent of rubber cement). It's not very large (relatively, compared to many other fantastical monsters), it would fit inside a pot of spaghetti. It can be just about any color, but sludge brown is the most common. It has four stalks, each tipped with a bouncy orb, on top of its head and an oral cavity it forms when it wants to eat something.

This tongue is long, flexible, and muscular enough to bind and pull in struggling prey. The oral cavity has teeth along the edges, which could be spines or stiffened psuedopods or even sharp cilia.

This creature happens to be both flexible, tough, and resilient.

The question is, how feasible is this creature? What adaptations does it need to exist?

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions, do you want to how this creature could exist, the specific traits it would need to survive, or its behavior? Sociology, evolutionary biology, and creature-design are all different concepts, try asking one, please.

Comment: Your requested features, such as the "long, flexible, and muscular" tongue and teeth, imply enough specialization that even if it was technically an amoeba colony it would not be meaningfully different from a single organism. You could narrow down this question by removing the parts about it possibly being an amoeba colony.

Comment: I feel like you're trying to build the world's creepiest zoo with all these bio questions.

Comment: How did you-I mean, what? Why would I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here again, just look to Nature!

What you've got here seems to be very much what an ordinary slug is.

You've described some extra bits which already exist elsewhere in the animal kingdom and would thus not be extraordinary in a spaghetti pot sized slug such as this fellow:

[image: stuff.co.nz]

Powerful tongues are well known, take for example the [chameleon's tongue](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/news/2016/01/160105-chameleons-tongue-speed-animals-science/). Slugs already have eye stalks, you just want a couple extras. Oral pseudopods could easily be explained by fluid pumps that increase their internal pressure thus making them very tough.

Slugs are already somewhat amorphous and are definitely slimy.  Mucus can be thin or thick & sticky, so no worries there.

Conclusion:
**Totally feasible.**

Comment: Wow, do you follow creature-design questions or something? You've answered two of my questions in a row, and you've done it quite well, thank you very much.

Comment: Well, you asked two in a row!

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to come up with a line of creatures for a series where the characters end up in a video game. I know feasibility shouldn't be a big issue there, but I hold myself to a higher standard.

Comment: Fair enough. You can hardly go wrong, when asking "is this creature feasible", to just look at the natural world around you. If creatures like giant sea slugs and chameleons *actually exist*, then the amalgamation of the two into a giant slug with a long sticky tongue is, at the very least, well within the realm of believable plausibility for any video game world!

Comment: Good point. I'm going to keep asking these questions, just so you know....and they will get progressively more difficult.

Comment: Bonus points if you can explain a mechanism for this slug monster eating something much bigger than it is!

Comment: Depends on what you mean here by "much bigger". Snakes, for example, can swallow prey that's pretty big. Your slug doesn't have a bony jaw, so it's more a matter of stretchiness of the oral orifice, so their prey could easily be as wide as themselves and perhaps rather longer!.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, that's very helpful!